# Post not working with Uri.builder

Tags: java, php, android, uri, httpurlconnection

For a registration form i am sending username, password and email id in httpurlconnection using the Uri.builder but there is a problem in receiving the value in the PHP side. I verified the response code its sending 200.

Java:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("username", user.username)
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", user.password)
                    .appendQueryParameter("email", user.email);

            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

           OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxxx");


   $username = $_POST["username"];
   $password = $_POST["password"];
   $email    = $_POST["email"];


 $sql = "INSERT INTO my_table(username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";


 mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 echo $email;

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The values are passing as username&password&email do i need to do some manipulation to re-fetch the values again?